# How to pass 2 array in json from php and how to parse it in android

Tags: php, arrays, json, string

I am creating the android application to communicate from android device to my localhost server. I want to pass two arrays from php file to android. But I don't know how to do that. Please help me for that.
I will search it a lot for this but I am not satisfy with my query.

Thanks in advance.

here is my php script.

```
<?php

// PHP variable to store the host address
$db_host  = "localhost";
// PHP variable to store the username
$db_uid  = "root";
// PHP variable to store the password
$db_pass = "";
// PHP variable to store the Database name  
$db_name  = "chatting"; 
// PHP variable to store the result of the PHP function 'mysql_connect()' which establishes the PHP & MySQL connection  
$db_con = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_uid,$db_pass) or die('could not connect');
mysql_select_db($db_name);

@$timestamp=$_POST["timestamp"];
@$message=$_POST["message"];
@$from=$_POST["from"];
@$to=$_POST["to"];
$from_id=1;//$_POST["from_id"];
$to_id=2;//$_POST["to_id"];

$sql1="INSERT INTO messages(from_msg,to_msg,message,timestamp) values('$from_id','$to_id','$message','$timestamp')";
$result1=mysql_query($sql1);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM messages";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
$output[]=$row["message"];

$sql="SELECT username FROM users WHERE id='".$from_id"'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);

$sql1="SELECT username from users where id='".$to_id"'";
$result1=mysql_query($sql1);
$row1=mysql_fetch_array($result1);
$chat[]=array(
'from_msg'=>$row['username'],
'to_msg'=>row1['username']);
print(json_encode($output,$chat));
mysql_close();   
?>
```

I want to parse this arrays in android.

Comment: Why dont you just merge them in a single array?

Comment: you can't pass two array variables in `json_encode()` function, merge them and do pass the single array into `json_encode()` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

either merge the arrays like
 `$newArray=array_merge($output,$chat);`
 Or create a multi dimensional array like
 `$newArray=array($output,$chat);`
and finally
 `json_encode($newArray);`

Comment: But I have a one question again is that how to decode them in android application?

Comment: this might help you http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/10/android-json-tutorial-create-and-parse-json-data.html